Let this be an N x N matrix, does this structure have a specific name?
The matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{1}{N^2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{N^2} \\
\frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{2}{N^2} & \frac{2}{N^2} & \cdots & \frac{2}{N^2} \\
\frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{2}{N^2} & \frac{3}{N^2} & \cdots & \frac{3}{N^2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{N^2} & \frac{2}{N^2} & \frac{3}{N^2} & \cdots & \frac{N}{N^2}
\end{pmatrix}
I have tried to look it up but without success. ChatGPT calls it a toeplitz matrix but that seems to be wrong.

arrow... like, I guess?

ChatGPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations (more). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "hallucinate" fake facts. Some extra examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.
